# заполнение пропусков в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, циклы

нужна помощь с заполнением пропусков.

У нас условный датафрейм. Столбец `goal` - это ключевой столбец, в котором есть много пропусков. Эти пропуски можно заполнить, ориентируясь на столбец `col_1`:

- Если в столбце присутствует диапазон значений.
  **Например:**
  *Первый диапазон цен:1500–1600* - тогда значением в `goal` будет медиана, как если бы у нас значения 1500 и 1600 были в разных строках.
- Если же в `col_1` указана одна сумма:
  **Например:**
  *Цена: от 1000* - тогда это значение и будет в столбце `goal`
- Если в столбце `col_1` имеется пропуск, либо иное значение, отличающееся от условий выше - тогда в `goal` ничего не будет, например оставляем пропуск.

В коде ниже попробовал сделать первые шаги по обработке:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['Первый диапазон цен:1500–1600',
                                  'Второй диапазон цен:155–185',
                                  'Цена:от 1000', np.nan]})

df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].str.strip(to_strip='Первый диапазон цен: от Второй диапазон цен: Цена:')
df['goal'] =  df['col_2'].str.replace('\D', ', ', regex=True)

df
```

Далее я нашел способ как вычислить медиану:

```
str_list = df['goal'].str.split(',')[0]
int_list = list(map(int, str_list))
np.median(int_list).astype(int)
```

Но это только для одной строки, дальше у меня не получается использовать такую задумку в цикле или в собственной функции, буду признателен если предложите выход из данной ситуации.

---

**UPD:**

Есть еще момент который я упустил:
В столбец `goal` должны войти не все значения, а только те, если строка в столбце `col_1` содержит определённое предложение. Так же есть столбец `goal_2`, в который войдут значения, которые по условию не могут вычисляться для `goal`. Например:

Для столбца `goal` вычисляется медиана (либо вставляем одно значение) если строка в `col_1` содержит например "Средний счёт:", тогда для столбца `goal_2` мы ничего не делаем (напр. оставляем NaN). Однако, если строка содержит "Цена одной чашки:", тогда для `goal` мы ничего не меняем, но для `goal_2` вычисляем медиану, либо вставляем одно значение (как я и писал до этого).

Пробовал так же поместить это в функцию:

```
def fill_na(df): 
    nans_g_1 = df['g_1'].isna()
    nans_g_2 = df['g_2'].isna()
    if df[df['col_1'].str.contains("Средний счёт:")]:
        df.loc[nans_avg, 'g_1'] = (df.loc[nans_avg, 'col_1']
                                               .str.replace(r'[^\d\u2013]', '', regex=True)
                                               .str.split('–', expand=True)
                                               .replace('', np.nan)
                                               .median(axis=1)
                                              )
    elif df[df['col_1'].str.contains("Цена одной чашки:")]:
        df.loc[nans_cof, 'g_2'] = (df.loc[nans_cof, 'col_1']
                                               .str.replace(r'[^\d\u2013]', '', regex=True)
                                               .str.split('–', expand=True)
                                               .replace('', np.nan)
                                               .median(axis=1)
                                              )
    return df
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: Поскольку вам для обработки нужны только значения одной строки данных, напишите просто функцию, которая будет принимать на вход строку данных, реализовывать логику с колонками и возвращать результат. И сделайте `apply` этой функции на датасет. Я только не помню может параметр `axis` нужно будет задать какой-то для построчной обработки. Результат присвойте в колонку `goal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение для расширенной задачки. Средние счета - в g_1, "одни чашки" - в g_2.

```
def fill_na(df):
    for col, cond in ('g_1', 'Средний счёт:'), ('g_2', 'Цена одной чашки:'):
        mask = df[col].isna() & df.col_1.str.contains(cond)
        df.loc[mask, col] = (df.loc[mask, 'col_1']
                             .str.replace(r'[^\d\u2013]', '', regex=True)
                             .str.split('–', expand=True)
                             .replace('', np.nan)
                             .median(axis=1)
                             )
    return df


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'g_1': [np.nan] * 4 + [111, np.nan], 'g_2': [np.nan] * 6, 'col_1': ['Средний счёт:1500–1600', 'Средний счёт:155–185', 'Цена одной чашки: от 1000', np.nan, 'Цена одной чашки: 300', 'Абракадабра']})
print(fill_na(df))
```

```
      g_1     g_2                      col_1
0  1550.0     NaN     Средний счёт:1500–1600
1   170.0     NaN       Средний счёт:155–185
2     NaN  1000.0  Цена одной чашки: от 1000
3     NaN     NaN                        NaN
4   111.0   300.0      Цена одной чашки: 300
5     NaN     NaN                Абракадабра
```

Answer (score 0):

Комментарии в коде

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'goal': [np.nan] * 4 + [111, np.nan], 'col_1': ['Первый диапазон цен:1500–1600', 'Второй диапазон цен:155–185', 'Цена:от 1000', np.nan, 'Цена: 300', 'Абракадабра']})
nans = df.goal.isna()  # булев массив для строк, где в goal - NAN, чтобы заменить только их
df.loc[nans, 'goal'] = df.loc[nans, 'col_1'].str.replace(r'[^\d\u2013]', '', regex=True).str.split('–', expand=True).replace('', np.nan).median(axis=1)  # удаляем все символы, кроме цифр и дефиса (дефис у вас не простой, а юникодный &#8211; или в HEX = 2013, потом распиливаем колонку на 2, заменяем пустые строки на NAN и берем медиану по горизонтальной оси
print(df)
```

```
     goal                          col_1
0  1550.0  Первый диапазон цен:1500–1600
1   170.0    Второй диапазон цен:155–185
2  1000.0                   Цена:от 1000
3     NaN                            NaN
4   111.0                      Цена: 300
5     NaN                    Абракадабра
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я упустил пару моментов... Дополнил свой вопрос. Если сможете помощь, буду благодарен.